# SQL statement - update several columns to different values depending on some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

`MyTable`:

```
id  | name | phone  | status1 | status2 | finalStatus
------------------------------------------------------
001 | Jack | 123456 |  good   |  good   |   X
002 | Jack | 123456 |  bad    |  good   |   X
003 | Jack | 123456 |  bad    |  bad    |   X
004 | Other| 000000 |  good   |  good   |   X
```

Given `[name]` and `[phone]`, if the `[status1]` and `[status2]` are good, then update `[finalStatus]` to good. Otherwise, update others to bad.

Therefore, given `Name=jack` and `phone=123456`, the result table I want should be as follows

```
id  | name | phone  | status1 | status2 | finalStatus
-----------------------------------------------------
001 | Jack | 123456 |  good   |  good   |   good   
002 | Jack | 123456 |  bad    |  good   |   bad
003 | Jack | 123456 |  bad    |  bad    |   bad
004 | Other| 000000 |  good   |  good   |   X
```

I did some research and found that I may use case when statement to do it. I have try the following code, but it does not work.

```
UPDATE [myTable]
SET finalStatus = (CASE
                      WHEN (status1 = 'Good' and status2 = 'Good')
                      THEN 'Good'
                      ELSE 'Bad'
                   END)
WHERE name = 'Jack' and phone = '123456'
```

**Updates:**

What I mean by "does not work" above is that the row is not really updated. However, I just figured out why it does not work for me. It is very stupid because I use the wrong table name (The names are very very similar).

However, I have tried the following codes

```
UPDATE [myTable]
SET finalStatus = (CASE
                      WHEN (status1 = 'Good' and status2 = 'Good' and name = 'Jack' and phone = '123456')
                      THEN 'Good'
                      ELSE 'Bad'
                   END)
```

The first row in the table above is set to 'Good', which is correct. However,  all other rows are set to bad. What is wrong with the above code? I thought it was the same as the first code above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you execute that statement?

Comment: If you're using a **case sensitive** collation, then maybe the fact that the tables contains `good` (in all lowercase) and you're checking for `Good` (with a capital `G`) could cause problems.... if you check for `WHEN (status1 = 'good' AND status2 = 'good')` - does that change anything? Does it work with these checks??

Comment: "I have try the following code, but it does not work", can you explain what "does not work" means here?

Comment: It isn't the same as before. Before you were only updating the rows where `name = 'Jack' and phone = '123456'`, now you changed your filter and `CASE` expression so now you look for **every row** of your table and if it isn't `Good, Good, Jack, 123456`, then the finalstatus is `Bad`, which is exactly what happened

Comment: @Lamak you are so right.. Now I understand..if you can move this to a post instead of comment, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this

DECLARE @Mytable TABLE
  (
     id          INT,
     name        VARCHAR(20),
     phone       INT,
     status1     VARCHAR(10),
     status2     VARCHAR(10),
     finalStatus VARCHAR(10)
  )

INSERT INTO @Mytable
VALUES     ('001',
            'Jack',
            '123456',
            'good',
            'good',
            'X'),
            ('002',
             'Jack',
             '123456',
             'bad',
             'good',
             'X'),
            ('003',
             'Jack',
             '123456',
             'bad',
             'bad',
             'X'),
            ('004',
             'Other',
             '000000',
             'good',
             'good',
             'X')

SELECT *
FROM   @Mytable

UPDATE @Mytable
SET    finalStatus = ( CASE
                         WHEN status1 = 'good'
                              AND status2 = 'good' THEN 'good'
                         ELSE 'bad'
                       END )
WHERE  name = 'jack'
       AND phone = '123456'

SELECT *
FROM   @Mytable
```